# How to use 4 spaces formatting for indentation in VSCode for Volar through Vue - Official extension in .vue files?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier, volar

I have a vuejs project and my team uses VSCode as the editor. I'm trying to setup a general project configuration for consistent autoformatting, including 4 space indentation instead of 2. I installed prettier as an NPM project dependency and the prettier extension for VSCode, then created a `.prettierrc` file to configure it. I set it as the default formatter in general and the default formatter for .js files and so forth in my VSCode `settings.json`. However, prettier didn't seem to run in .vue files. So i installed the `Vue - Official` extension which apparently provides Volar for vuejs formatting. As you can see, i specified it in my VSCode settings and also explicitely set the indentation with to 4 spaces, the same for prettier.

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 4,

  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[css]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
  },

  "files.autoSave": "off", // Disable auto-save on focus change
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark"
}
```

Here is my .prettierrc for reference:

```
{
    "semi": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 80,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "useTabs": false
}
```

However, while some sort of formatting seems to run now in .vue files, it still only uses 2 spaces. Why? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You try to check `save` in settings of VScode, if `Editor: Format On Save` doesn't check, please check it.

And in settings, you press `prettier` and change tabWidth to 4.

Finally, right click in your html file -> select `Format Document With...` -> select `Config default formatter...` -> select `Prettier - Code Formatter`.

I hope something above will help you resolve your problem.